# subtract every next column value from previous?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rapidminer

I have a dataset, where somehow the next singular data is added on top of the previous data for one row, and that for every column, which means,
row with ID 1 is the original pure data, but row with e.g ID 10 has added the data from the previous 9 datasets on itself...

what I now want is to get the original pure data for every distinct item, which means for every ID, how can I substract all data from lets say ID, 10? I would have to substract those of the previous one, for ID 9 and so on...

I want to do this either in SQL Server or in Rapidminer, I am working with those tools, any idea?
here is a sample:

```
ID  col1 col2 col3 
1    12   2     3
2    15   5     5
3    20   8     8
```

so the real correct data for Item with ID 3 is not 20, 8, 8  it is (20-15),(8-5),(8-5) so its 5,3,3...
subtract the later from its previous for every item except the first..

1    12   2     3

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out with `lag series` operator, it will work for sure! To get this operator you should install the series extension from the RM marketplace.

What this operator does - he copies the selected attributes and pushes every row of the example set for one point, so row with ID 1 gets a copy with ID 2 etc (you can also specify the value for a lag). Afterwards you can substract one value from another with `Generate Attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `lag()` is the answer to your question:

```
select (case when id = 1 then col
             else col - lag(col) over (order by id)
        end)
```

However, sample data would clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Within RapidMiner there is the `Differentiate` operator contained in the Series extension (which is not installed by default and needs to be downloaded from the RapidMiner Marketplace). This can be used to calculate differences between attributes in adjacent examples.